# iOS httprequest data recovery

Tags: ios, http

I'm having problem with getting data from my http client on iOS. This is my code for client class

```
@synthesize receivedData;

- (void) HTTPRequest1 :(NSURL *) url {
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];


    if (connect) {
        receivedData =[NSMutableData data];

    }
    else {

    }


}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];


}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

        [self.receivedData appendData:data];
    //receivedData

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);



}
```

but when i'm trying to get data from this client:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ya.ru"];
MAHTTPClient *client = [MAHTTPClient alloc];
[client HTTPRequest1:url];
 NSMutableData *data = client.receivedData;
```

data variable is empty, but data was received (NSLog showed the fact of downloading some bytes of data). The problem is that my app is trying retrieve data when it still hasn't been downloaded from server (there is 200 ms difference) is there any way to make main thread to wait until connectionDidFinishLoading is called?

Answer (score 0):

The NSMutableData that you're allocating here:

```
if (connect) {
    receivedData =[NSMutableData data];

}
else {

}
```

is probably being autoreleased, since you're using a method that return an autoreleased object.

You should either do something like:

```
self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
```

IF the receivedData is a strong/retain property OR

```
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

// but you need to understand the memory management rules to make sure that you're not leaking memory here.

Comment: still not working, i cannot retrieve data from my client, but when I try to access data in connectionDidFinishLoading method, receivedData  contains everything received from server, but still when I access received Data from my view controller it's empty